# libGDX touch in effect after touch

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I use the following code to match the user touch to a ball object's position, so when the user touches the ball it bounce back up. Code:

```
int x1 = Gdx.input.getX();
int y1 = Gdx.input.getY();
Vector3 input = new Vector3(x1, y1, 0);
cam.unproject(input);

if(ball.getBoundingCircle().contains(input.x, input.y)) {
ballBounce();
}
```

But I have a problem with the touch. If the user touches a certain position on screen for a moment and a ball (after a while more appear) about to reach the position the user touched, the ball will recognize itself as been touched and the ballBounce(); method will start and continue with other balls that reach to the same position until the user touch another position on the screen but then that position will be fixed till the new one... Do someone know how I can bypass that problem so if the user stop touching the screen then where he\she touched won't affect the ball objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are not using any input processor.
Make your class implement InputProcessor and make your touchDown method look like this.

```
@Override
touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    Vector3 input = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
    cam.unproject(input);

    if (ball.getBoundingCircle().contains(input.x, input.y)) {
        ballBounce();
    }
}
```

[ClickListener (LibGDX API)](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ClickListener.html)

Comment: When I searched for a code to recognize user touch with object's position that is the example I encountered most of the time. So to your question, I don't.

Comment: Then you should implement InputProcessor and add your code inside touchDown or clicked, so that your input vector coordinates are deleted when player releases his/hers finger and the coordinates update when player presses again.

Comment: Then can I use only the touchDown? Or unless I give a specific commend for the coordinated to be deleted on touchUp, the problem will still remain?

Comment: If you use it in the method touchDown, it stops scanning when you are not touching anymore, so no need to add anything to the touchUp method. Just test it.

Comment: Good to know that I only need to deal with the touchDown commend, but I'm still having problems with it and wonder if you can continue to help me? Can I just implements the InputProcessor with the touchDown method and inside it use the method with the ball's conditions (including the one above) and use the touchDown's parameters in the "contains(input.x, input.y)" (instead the "input...")?